# How to display fieldsname on the leftside and it's value on the rightside in datagridview in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

```
 Private Sub OpenFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenFileToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "mdb files (*.mdb)|*.mdb|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True


    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                myConString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & openFileDialog1.FileName
                Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT Image001 FROM [DDCOS] WHERE RecNum = @RecNum", con)
                con.ConnectionString = myConString



                Dim path As New IO.DirectoryInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName)
                Dim childLen As Integer = path.Name.Length 
                Dim parentLen As Integer = path.Parent.Name.Length
                Dim path2 As String = openFileDialog1.FileName.Substring(0, openFileDialog1.FileName.Length - (childLen + parentLen + 1)) & "Images"  
  con.Open()

                datagridshow()
            End If
        Catch Ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot read file from disk. Original error: " & Ex.Message)
        Finally
            ' Check this again, since we need to make sure we didn't throw an exception on open. 

            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                myStream.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CARD_DECK_ENTRY_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    con.ConnectionString = myConString
    con.Open()
    datagridshow()
End Sub

Private Sub datagridshow()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ODDA As New OleDbDataAdapter

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Data001", con)
    da.Fill(dt)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

    con.Close()

End Sub
```

---

The above code was my code on browsing an mdb and input it's value on the datagrid. And I was about to display the fieldsname on the leftside and the value of it on the right side. How it supposed to do?

Comment: what are you getting now in `datagridview1`? and how many columns your table contains?

Comment: i can browse an mdb and display it on datagridview. Like a normal database, when it displayed the column fields of it was literally align in one row (horizontal). And I'm about to set the column fields align vertical and assign on the left side and it's value on the right side. Can you help me do this matter?

Comment: it having 20 column fields

Comment: Means you want to display `columns` in `datatable` as `rows` in `datagridview`, right? or I can say vice versa

Comment: yes your right. every column = 1row. Ex: Column1 = 1st row , Column2 = 2nd row, Column3 = 3rdrow and so on. Could you help me do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per I got your problem,

1. You need to create a new `datatable`.
2. Add required numbers of `column` in `datatable` with names.
3. Add new `row` to `datatable` iteratively.
4. Fill new `row` with data in `column` of `datatable` filled using `OleDb` `Query`.
5. And then `bind` this new `datatable` to `datagridview` as `datasource`.

This may help you.

Comment: is the value of every column will be on the right side after doing this?

Comment: @Jham yes surely it will.

Comment: sorry, maybe your sure but afterall I dont know how to do it. Sad to say I am newbie in programming. </3